# Add custom option (text + value) in a select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to add an "Other" option with the value -1 in this select:

```
<%= f.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicles, :id, :model, "@used_vehicles[i]") %>
```

Should I replace `@vehicles` with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, you should use the already existant behaviour in Rails, which is to use the `include_blank` option:

```
<%= f.select(:id, @vehicles.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'Other'}) %>
```

You can check the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) also.